# GAE Internal Server Error URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out>

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

On GAE I want to download file from FTP server,on my local development environment ,it work well. But when the application is run on GAE, it has followed error. Any Suggestion? Thanks for your help.

```
167.220.232.24 - - [09/Jun/2014:08:51:00 -0700] "GET /task/updateShipStatus/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10812 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36" "******.appspot.com" ms=19543 cpu_ms=2274 cpm_usd=0.001214 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c1ae14d753986063e6a1d8ac230349b app_engine_release=1.9.5
   E 23:50:44.530 *get* '220 LR-Fairplay FTP Server ready...\r\n'

   E 23:50:44.530 *resp* '220 LR-Fairplay FTP Server ready...'

   E 23:50:44.530 *cmd* 'USER bunge2'

   E 23:50:44.530 *put* 'USER bunge2\r\n'

   E 23:50:44.530 *get* '331 User name okay, need password.\r\n'

   E 23:50:44.530 *resp* '331 User name okay, need password.'

   E 23:50:44.530 *cmd* 'PASS ********'

   E 23:50:44.530 *put* 'PASS ********\r\n'

   E 23:50:44.530 *get* '230 User logged in, proceed.\r\n'
   E 23:50:44.530 *resp* '230 User logged in, proceed.'
   E 23:50:44.530 *cmd* 'CWD ./'
   E 23:50:44.530 *put* 'CWD ./\r\n'
   E 23:50:44.530 *get* 
   E 23:50:59.896 Internal Server Error: /task/updateShipStatus/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response

    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~precise-rune-588/1.376434829982431426/googlemapapp/views.py", line 227, in updateShipStatus

    ftp.retrbinary('RETR 201406050450_combinedpositionsdata.txt', r.write, bufsize)

  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 409, in retrbinary

    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)

  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 371, in transfercmd

    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]

  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 330, in ntransfercmd

    conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)

  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 569, in create_connection

    raise err
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

   E 23:51:00.232 '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'

   E 23:51:00.232 *resp* '250 Directory changed to /'

   E 23:51:00.232 *cmd* 'TYPE I'

   E 23:51:00.232 *put* 'TYPE I\r\n'

   E 23:51:00.232 *get* '200 Type set to I.\r\n'

   E 23:51:00.232 *resp* '200 Type set to I.'

   E 23:51:00.232 *cmd* 'PASV'

   E 23:51:00.232 *put* 'PASV\r\n'

   E 23:51:00.232 *get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (216,35,233,26,7,176)\r\n'

   E 23:51:00.232 *resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (216,35,233,26,7,176)'

   I 23:51:00.236 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Comment: Google has confirmed this is a GAE bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can make outbound connections however you are going to face a number of potential limitations.

Firstly

```
1 billing must be enabled
2. there are strict timeouts
3. some restrictions in destinations and ports.
4. And if you run this from a frontend request, then you will need to do all your work inside 60 second.
5. no inbound sockets.
```

As to the specific timeout will require investigation.  You may be blocked.  In theory PASV ftp should work, but normal ftp can not. I have not tried this.